# Is it possible to interrupt the Data being inserted by a Template?

Tags: acumatica

Let's suppose that we define a Sales Order Template that includes Summary information and Document Details lines.

The user would normally use this template with the Toolbar button: Clipboard > Paste from [Template].

Is it possible to use the same template in 2 ways?

1- The standard full data insertion

2- Include an event that interrupts the insertion of the grid lines. Only the summary would be inserted.

I was thinking of extending the FieldUpdated event and use a .Ask() dialog box to offer the options to the user. And the event is certainly triggered. But I do not know how to interrupt the rest of the data from being inserted if the user selects option 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For full canceling insertion from Clipboard, you can use the following in your graph:

```
public override bool CanClipboardCopyPaste()
{
  return false;
}
```

Also you can use attribute PXCopyPasteHiddenFields. That attribute says that specified fields of the primary DAC of the data view will no be copied when the copy-paste feature is used.

Another attribute which you can consider is PXCopyPasteHiddenView. This attribute says that cache corresponding to the primary DAC of the data view is not copied when the copy-paste feature is used.

And one more useful fields in graph itself is IsCopyPasteContext. If it is set to true, then it means that currently we are in process of creation of records.

Below goes example of usage:

```
if (this.IsCopyPasteContext)
{
    sender.SetValue<APPayment.printed>(row, false);
    sender.SetDefaultExt<APPayment.printCheck>(row);
}
```

Comment: Great info! Is it possible to paste the content of an identified AUTemplate.TemplateID on run time? For instance, in the CustomerID_FieldUpdated event.

Comment: yes, IsCopyPasteContext will be available in that method

Comment: Thanks Yura. Yes, access to the IsCopyPasteContext flag works great. In my previous comment I meant to ask if it's possible to run the Paste Template button in the FieldUpdated event. For instance, after the Customer ID is changed. Something along the lines of this.Actions.PressSave but oriented to the clipboard perhaps. Thanks again